# How to plot a linegraph in SPSS with respect to the data?

Tags: data-visualization, spss

[image]

Hi all,

Above you'll see a line-graph plotted with SPSS. I want to improve this line-graph according to its data. Meaning that some elements are not presented correctly:

(1) I deliberately adjusted the scaling on the Y-axis from -1 to 10, in order to notice the breaks (i.e. missing values) in the line graph. Otherwise you'll not notice the breaks, as it will overlap with the bottom-line of the graph. Is it possible to notice the breaks, but with a scaling of 0 to 10 (in SPSS)? > ***SOLVED***

(2) On the X-axis, point 14 and 15 are missing, hence the break. However, the line graph shows an upward trend just after point 13, and a downward trend just before point 16. Is it possible to adjust the line-graph (in SPSS), which would delete these described (interpolation) trends?

```
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=Time_Period_Hours
    MEAN(MT)[name="MEAN_MT"] MISSING=VARIABLEWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: Time_Period_Hours=col(source(s), name("Time_Period_Hours"), unit.category())
  DATA: MEAN_MT=col(source(s), name("MEAN_MT"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), delta(1))
  SCALE: linear(dim(2), min(-0.5), max(9))
  ELEMENT: line(position(Time_Period_Hours*MEAN_MT))
  ELEMENT: point(position(Time_Period_Hours*MEAN_MT), color(color.black), 
                 size(size."3px"))
END GPL.
```

Comment: I discuss some of these issues in a blog post, https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/aggregating-values-in-time-series-charts/. The interpolation you note for question 2 is due to the `missing.wings()` function (which is the default). The scaling answer would need an example of your data, it is not clear to me if the x-axis is being treated as categorical or scale.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I noticed in your blog that you use `min(-0.5)` for the scaling on the Y-axis. This actually solved my first question, as "-0.5" is not shown -and "0" just starts slightly higher on the Y-axis!

As for the `missing.wings()`; just by removing it in the syntax did unfortunately not help.
(x-axis is categorical btw)

Comment: You will need to provide a reproducible example to give any further help. I can only guess what the syntax looks like currently.

Comment: @AndyW updated my question with syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, for the line element you need to specify the option `missing.gap()` - I thought just deleting `missing.wings()` from the default code would work but maybe it is an internal default. You may want to consider changing `Time_Period_Hours` to a scale variable and doing the aggregation outside of `GGRAPH`. Also making the Y axis scale in your example go all the way up to 9 seems a bit superfluous.

```
DATA LIST FREE / Time_Period_Hours MT.
BEGIN DATA
1 1
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 1
6 0
7 0
8 0
9 0
10 0
11 .
12 0
13 0
14 .
15 .
16 1
17 0
18 0
19 0
20 .
21 0
END DATA.
FORMATS Time_Period_Hours MT (F2.0).
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=Time_Period_Hours
    MEAN(MT)[name="MEAN_MT"] MISSING=VARIABLEWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: Time_Period_Hours=col(source(s), name("Time_Period_Hours"), unit.category())
  DATA: MEAN_MT=col(source(s), name("MEAN_MT"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), delta(1))
  SCALE: linear(dim(2), min(-0.5), max(9))
  ELEMENT: line(position(Time_Period_Hours*MEAN_MT), missing.gap())
  ELEMENT: point(position(Time_Period_Hours*MEAN_MT), color(color.black), 
                 size(size."3px"))
END GPL.
```

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much :). 
(Btw: the Y-axis is up to 10, because I need to be consistent in scaling in all my graphs; this was just one example of a whole serie)